# ListView designing on the Android

Tags: android, android-listview

This is my XML for showing `user's information` on the `ListView`, So currently it contains two `TextView` on which I am showing user's information.

**Problem Statement:-**

Whenever I run my application, I always see both of my `Text View` coming side by side. For example I always get something like below-

```
SomeImage             TextView1             TextView2
```

Which is what I don't want. I need something like this- And suppose if I have three TextView in future.

```
SomeImage             TextView1

                      TextView2

                      TextView3
```

And below is my XML file which I am using currently. How can I modify this so that I always get the required output I need?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/stub" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="10dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="10dip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Consider to change to a `RelativeLayout` instead of a `LinearLayout` and you will be successful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="50dip"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/stub" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:text="TextView1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:text="TextView2" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:text="TextView3" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

`LinearLayout`'s orientation is *[horizontal by default](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android%3aorientation)*. Just add this line to your `<LinearLayout>`

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```